# How to find a basis of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ be the vector space of $2\times 2$ traceless matrices. Let $A\in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ be a diagonal matrix. Define a linear operator $\phi_A: sl_2\to sl_2$:
$$\phi_A(X)=AX-XA$$

I want to show that $\phi_A$ is diagonalisable and find a basis of eigenvectors and the corresponding eigenvalues.

Now traceless means that any matrix in $sl_2$ will be of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{bmatrix}$$

The basis is $$\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&-A\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&B\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\C&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

And an arbitrary $A$, diagonal and in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ looks like $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&0\\0&-a_1\end{bmatrix}$

so we get

\begin{eqnarray} 
\phi_A(X_1)&=&0\\
\phi_A(X_2)&=&\begin{bmatrix}0&2a_1 B\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
\phi_A(X_3)&=&\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-2a_1C&0\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

> So how do I find the basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: You mean like vectors $X_1’, X_2’, X_3’$ such that $ϕ_A(X_1’) = 0·X_1’$, $ϕ_A(X_2’) = 2a_1·X_2’$ and $ϕ_A(X_3’) = -2a_1·X_3’$ for example? Hm, …

Comment: You find them by taking a good look at what you wrote down.

Comment: @AdLibitum I am confused because I don't know how to write $\phi_A$ generically perhaps. I was told it should be a $3\times 3$ matrix, but I don't see it.

Comment: In general, you'd write the matrix associated to $\varphi_A$ (which is $3\times3$ because the space has dimension 3) and you try to diagonalize it. But if you know what eigenvectors and eigenvalues are, a good look at your computations reveals that you have already solved the problem.

Comment: P.S.: To make it perhaps more visible, just take $A=B=C=1$ (which makes for the natural choice of a basis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that

$$ \phi_A(X_1)= 0 \cdot  X_1$$
$$\phi_A(X_2) = 2 a_1  \cdot X_2$$
$$\phi_A(X_3) = -2 a_1  \cdot X_3$$
holds. Thus $X_1$ is a eigenvector of $\phi$ with eigenvalue $0$, $X_2$ is a eigenvector with eigenvalue $2 a_1$ and $X_3$ is a eigenvector with eigenvalue $-2 a_1$.

A matrix representation $M\in\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ of your function $\phi_A$ according to your basis $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ is definied such that for $$X=\alpha_1 X_1 + \alpha_2 X_2 + \alpha_3 X_3$$ and $$\phi_A(X)=\beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3$$
you have 
$$ M \left(\begin{matrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \\ \beta_3\end{matrix}\right).$$
So, its easy to see that
$$M = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 a_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 a_1 \end{matrix} \right).$$

Comment: This was very helpful, I get it now, thank you!